# Problems with rerouting requests to a specific ip and port in IIS?

Tags: java, iis

I have the following scenario and would like to seek some advise. I have a web application that I wrote for my company. Its purely in C#. My company mainly uses dot net for their development. Now, I have hosted the application on the local network on a specific port. Here is the catch- my company has only one port open to the public where the Apache server is hosted for accepting incoming requests. They dont want to host my application on a different public port and they want me to do something such that I can host the java application on that specific public port which is not possible.
I was thinking of redirecting - a service that is hosted on that public port and redirects to the port where my application is hosted. Again, my boss doesnt want me to expose the url of the application to the public. He just wants me to redirect without exposing the ip and port.
Can someone suggest me some solution. I have worked on redirecting in Nginx before but I dont know if there is a way to configure something like that in IIS.

Thanks

Comment: My recommendation would be to find a server administrator that understands IIS. All of your tags are a bunch of spam IMO

Comment: So your employer has a single domain with a single port (80) that is publicly accessible? [You shouldn't expose important services over any ports other than 80/443](https://serverfault.com/questions/734937/is-it-safe-to-serve-http-https-over-ports-8080-8443). You can't redirect, because that will require the target service to be exposed to the web, necessarily (due to business constraints) on the same port. This is impossible. IMO, your only option here is to use IIS as a proxy to your other service. What's running on IIS? With WebAPI, proxying can be very easy to do programmatically.

Comment: otherwise, take a look for "reverse proxy IIS" in your favourite search engine. Here's something interesting: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's presume if your Java website is hosted on local network (192.168.1.2) with port 8080. And it is accessible from the browser by this url:
http://192.168.1.2:8080 from IIS server.

And you want to make it accessible by this domain: http://example.com

1. You need to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS
2. Enable ARR. On the `Application Request Routing` page, select `Enable proxy`
3. Add Website from applications Pools -> Site Name(`example.com`)
4. Physical path (`C:\example.com`)
5. Add binding for `example.com` and port 80
6. Create web.config in `C:\example.com` folder

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration>`

   ```
   <system.webServer>  
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
              <rule name="rewrite to 8080" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="(.*)" />
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://192.168.1.2:8080/{R:1}" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

   `</configuration>`